# Discharging lithium-ion battery

Tags: lithium-ion, discharge

I have a 3.7 V lithium-ion battery, 10000 mAh. Is there any way to discharge it? I do not have a Li-ion battery discharger.

Any recommendation about what I could plug in? I tried a firestick thinking that it doesn't have an internal battery and that the voltage is 5 V but there is no current flow because the voltage isn't high enough to power.

Comment: May I ask why you want to discharge a battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Li-ion battery includes a protector BMS, then simply connect it to a load, such a small lamp. When the cell is fully discharged, the BMS will shut off the current and protect the cells.

Otherwise, it gets complicated because you risk over-discharging the cell. You would need a voltmeter and patience as you watch the cell slowly discharge, so you can remove the load when the voltage is low but not too low.

Comment: Thank You so much You are a lifesaver. I am heading to target right now to buy a little lamp. Way cheaper than a lipo discharger.

Comment: But if the battery does not have a BMS then it will get too discharged and battery will degrade or damage. Also, if the battery does have a BMS, the BMS may cut off and disable the pack permanently before it damages, so either way, you end up with disabled battery. Sometimes they wake up when charging voltage is applied, sometimes they don't.